# Reference request: introduction to $C^*$-algebras (at a preferably undergraduate level)

Tags: linear-algebra, abstract-algebra, functional-analysis, reference-request

I am looking for either:

- An introductory text to $C^*$-algebras and operator theory accessible to someone with an early undergraduate understanding of abstract algebra and some functional analysis. There are quite a few books on this subject, but I am not sure where they fall on the 'graduate-level vs. undergraduate-level' spectrum.

Or:

- A roadmap of texts for someone with an undergraduate level understanding of abstract algebra and a light understanding of functional analysis to be able to dig into introductory graduate texts on $C^*$-algebras.

And any comments on what may be appropriate in my endeavor.

Comment: You might find [these notes](https://math.dartmouth.edu/~dana/bookspapers/cstar.pdf) by Dana Williams helpful.